# Which WPF control can I use to draw a graph?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

In the `Paint` event of a `Panel` I'm drawing some horizontal lines in Windows form. Then I pass the `Graphics` object to a function to draw other graphs on horizontal lines.

Now I have to draw same horizontal lines in WPF and draw other graphs on horizontal lines (use XBAP to show WPF within the browser). I don't know what to use in WPF to draw a graph dynamically (I have to show graph in a browser).

```
private void pnlViewer_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int cellWidth = (int)((double)1024/ (double)50);
    int cellHeight = (int)((double)768/ (double)50);

    //Draw Horizontal lines.
    int y;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
    {
        y = (i * cellHeight) + cellHeight;
        using (var pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(50, 50, 50)))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, y), new Point(1024, y));
        }
        DrawGraph(e.Graphics);
    }
}
```

Comment: canvas will be best fit for you.

Comment: You may start reading the [Shapes and Basic Drawing in WPF Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx) article on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

Try drawing all of this on a Canvas.

To do this, you can just use Canvas.SetTop(object, location) and Canvas.SetLeft

Answer (score 1):

If you want to lower your pain try [Visifire](http://www.visifire.com)